# AWS HTTP API Integration with AWS Step Functions -> Send Multiple Values in the Input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions, aws-http-api

I have a `Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi` which I am trying to connect to a `Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine` as a trigger. Meaning the HTTP API would trigger the Step Function state machine.

I can get it working, by only specifying a single input. For example, the `DefinitionBody` when it works, looks like this:

```yaml
      DefinitionBody:
        info:
          version: '1.0'
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        paths:
          "/github/secret":
            post:
              responses: 
                default:
                  description: "Default response for POST /"
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                integrationSubtype: "StepFunctions-StartExecution"
                credentials:
                  Fn::GetAtt: [StepFunctionsApiRole, Arn]
                requestParameters:
                  Input: $request.body
                  StateMachineArn: !Ref SecretScannerStateMachine
                payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
                type: "aws_proxy"
                connectionType: "INTERNET"
                timeoutInMillis: 30000
        openapi: 3.0.1
        x-amazon-apigateway-importexport-version: "1.0"
```

Take note of the following line: `Input: $request.body`. I am only specifying the `$request.body`.

However, I need to be able to send the `$request.body` and `$request.header.X-Hub-Signature-256`. I need to send BOTH these values to my state machine as an input.

I have tried so many different ways. For example:

```yaml
Input: " { body: $request.body, header: $request.header.X-Hub-Signature-256 }"
```

and

```yaml
Input:
  $request.body
  $request.header.X-Hub-Signature-256
```

and

```yaml
Input: $request
```

Nothing seems to work. I am trying to follow the documentation here:

- [Working with OpenAPI definitions for HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-open-api.html).
- [x-amazon-apigateway-integration object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html)
- [x-amazon-apigateway-integration.requestParameters object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestParameters.html)
- [Working with AWS service integrations for HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services.html)
- [StepFunctions-StartExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services-reference.html#StepFunctions-StartExecution)
- [StartExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html)

But nothing seems to point on how to pass multiple vars, only one.

I get different errors each time, but this is the main one:

```
Warnings found during import: Unable to create integration for resource at path 'POST /github/secret': Invalid selection expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid source: $request specified for destination: Input].
```

Any help on how to pass multiple values would so be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [repost.aws post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUEmu00NfnQzO0_5FUuKFJ6A/passing-http-headers-from-api-gateway-http-api-to-step-function) which describes a similar scenario:

> What you want is not supported by HTTP API. You can achieve this with REST API and request mapping.

So try using a REST API instead.